# SQL Query needed for generating a complex report

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to write a SQL code to derive a report from one of my tables which look like this:

```
    EmployeeId  Date    ProjectId   Hours   Approved
    123         12/7    A1          8       Y
    123         12/8    A1          5       Y
    123         12/9    A2          6       Y
    123         12/9    A1          2       Y
    123         12/14   A1          8       Y
    123         12/15   A1          5       N
    123         12/16   A2          6       Y
    123         12/16   A1          2       Y
    123         12/21   A1          8       Y
    123         12/22   A1          5       Y
    123         12/23   A2          6       Y
    123         12/23   A1          2       Y
```

The format of report that I am expecting is:

```
    EmployeeId  Project     WeekStart   SundayHours MondayHours TuesdayHours    WednesdayHours  ThursdayHours   FridayHours SaturdayHours
    123         A1              12/7        0          8           5             2
    123         A2              12/7        0          0           0             6
    123         A1              12/21       0          8           5             2
    123         A2              12/21       0          0           0             6
```

There is one condition also. I need to include employees record only if his time for whole week has been approved. In the above example, the hours of 12/15 were not approved. Hence, the records of week of 12/14 are not displayed in the report.

Also, I need to include only last 3 weeks of data. That is, if the report is run on 12/26, it should give the records of week of 12/7, 12/14 and 12/21.

I have no clue where to start. Can anyone help me out in generationg such a reportss

Comment: This is called Conditional aggregation. Have a search of that, you'll find loads of resources

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend manipulating the dates to act as grouping mechanismS, and then simply do some conditional summing.

The beauty of dates is that you can easily extract things like day of week names, week numbers, etc. In this example I've used the week number to filter out the weeks that have unapproved records (see the JOIN), and also to get the minimum date (WeekStart).

However, this isn't foolproof. If there is no Monday record then the WeekStart might not be what you are expecting

```
SELECT
EmployeeId
,ProjectId
,WeekStart
,SUM(IIF(DATENAME(WEEKDAY,Date)='Sunday',Hours,0)) SundayHours
,SUM(IIF(DATENAME(WEEKDAY,Date)='Monday',Hours,0)) MondayHours
,SUM(IIF(DATENAME(WEEKDAY,Date)='Tuesday',Hours,0)) TuesdayHours
,SUM(IIF(DATENAME(WEEKDAY,Date)='Wednesday',Hours,0)) WednesdayHours
,SUM(IIF(DATENAME(WEEKDAY,Date)='Thursday',Hours,0)) ThursdayHours
,SUM(IIF(DATENAME(WEEKDAY,Date)='Friday',Hours,0)) FridayHours
,SUM(IIF(DATENAME(WEEKDAY,Date)='Saturday',Hours,0)) SaturdayHours
FROM #WorkHours WH
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
    DATEPART(WEEK,Date) WeekNumber
    ,MIN(Date) WeekStart
    FROM #WorkHours
    GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(WEEK,Date)
    HAVING SUM(IIF(Approved='N',1,0)) = 0
    ) Approved
    ON DATEPART(WEEK,WH.Date) = Approved.WeekNumber
GROUP BY
EmployeeId
,WeekStart
,ProjectId
ORDER BY
EmployeeId
,WeekStart
,ProjectId
```

Comment: Conditional aggregation is indeed the way to go. But you don't even the join logic. You can aggregate just once, in the outer query.

Comment: That's a good point, you are right. My mind headed in a different direction first and I kept some of that code.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server defines weeks as starting on a Sunday.  You have no year in your data, so let me assume that is what you intend.

Then you can simply use conditional aggregation:

```
select EmployeeId,
       dateadd(day, 7 - datepart(weekday, Date)) as week,
       ProjectId,
       sum(case when datename(weekday, Date) = 'Sunday' then Hours else 0 end) as sunday_hours,
       sum(case when datename(weekday, Date) = 'Monday' then Hours else 0 end) as monday_hours,
       . . . 
from #WorkHours wh
group by EmployeeId, dateadd(day, 7 - datepart(weekday, Date)), ProjectId
```